# Linker Error with FacebookSDK integration for IOS App in SWIFT3

Tags: ios, swift3, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am getting a linker error with the Facebook SDK integration and I am currently using swift 3. Below is a screenshot of the error. 
[image]

Comment: You did not add the `Bolts` framework to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I think I found the answer. I basically needed to add the Bolts.framework folder into my Xcode project. That resolved the linker issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not answer your own question. Edit your question instead.